# gdb representation of unsigned char -- is it inconsistent?

Tags: c++, gdb

I've been debugging a segfault in some numerical code (C++, no dependencies on any external libraries).  I've got it reproducing the segfault when compiled at optimization level -O0 (using gcc) and run within gdb; the backtrace I get is:

```
(gdb) backtrace 2
#0  0x000000000040171c in QExpFloorLog_Q_R (q=Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefec) at GlobalFunctions.hpp:11
#1  0x0000000000401b50 in MinExponentFromTheoremTwo (q=2, k_q=20 '\024', r=1122053) at GlobalFunctions.hpp:90
```

The signature of MinExponentFromTheoremTwo is:

```
unsigned char MinExponentFromTheoremTwo(const unsigned int q, const unsigned char k_q, const unsigned int r);
```

So, my question is:  what am I to make of `k_q=20 '\024'`?  I understand that k_q is an unsigned char, and therefore that gdb is giving me both a numerical value and an ascii representation; I have other places with unsigned char variables listed as `var1=0 '\000'`, `var2=1 '\001'`, etc.  But k_q seems mismatched, with a value of 20 and a code of \024.  Am I misunderstanding how unsigned char are used, or should this be helping me find the bug in my code?

Incidentally, I have

```
$ uname -a
Linux clayton-AOD255E 2.6.38-13-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 28 19:33:45 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number called twenty is represented in base 10 as '20'. In base 8, it is '24'. `\024` is the octal representation of that value.

All of the following are the same value:

```
20     // decimal, base-10
024    // octal, base-8
'\024' // octal, base-8
0x14   // hex, base-16
```

Comment: Gotcha -- makes perfect sense, thanks!
(And you answered too quickly -- 5 minutes until I can accept :) )